# Input 0 of layer lstm_5 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm

I am trying to create an image captioning model. Could you please help with this error? input1 is the image vector, input2 is the caption sequence. 32 is the caption length. I want to concatenate the image vector with the embedding of the sequence and then feed it to the decoder model.

```
    def define_model(vocab_size, max_length):
      input1 = Input(shape=(512,))
      input1 = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(32)(input1)
      print(input1.shape)

      input2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))
      e1 = Embedding(vocab_size, 512, mask_zero=True)(input2)
      print(e1.shape)

      dec1 = tf.concat([input1,e1], axis=2)
      print(dec1.shape)

      dec2 = LSTM(512)(dec1)
      dec3 = LSTM(256)(dec2)
      dec4 = Dropout(0.2)(dec3)
      dec5 = Dense(256, activation="relu")(dec4)
      output = Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax")(dec5)
      model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)
      model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")
      print(model.summary())
      return model
```

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_5 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 512]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This error occurs when an LSTM layer gets input in 2D instead of 3D. For instance:**

```
(64, 100)
```

The correct format is `(n_samples, time_steps, features)`:

```
(64, 5, 100)
```

In this case, the mistake you did was that the input of `dec3`, which is an LSTM layer, was the output of `dec2`, which is also an LSTM layer. By default, the argument `return_sequences` in an LSTM layer is `False`. This means that the first LSTM returned a 2D tensor, which was incompatible with the next LSTM layer. I solved your issue by setting `return_sequences=True` in your first LSTM layer.

Also, there was an error in this line:

```
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)
```

`input1` was not an input layer because you reassigned it. See:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(512,))
input1 = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(32)(input1)
```

I renamed the second one `e0`, consistent with how you're naming your variables.

Now, everything is working:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import Input

vocab_size, max_length = 1000, 32

input1 = Input(shape=(128))
e0 = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(32)(input1)
print(input1.shape)

input2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))
e1 = Embedding(vocab_size, 128, mask_zero=True)(input2)
print(e1.shape)

dec1 = Concatenate()([e0, e1])
print(dec1.shape)

dec2 = LSTM(16, return_sequences=True)(dec1)
dec3 = LSTM(16)(dec2)
dec4 = Dropout(0.2)(dec3)
dec5 = Dense(32, activation="relu")(dec4)
output = Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax")(dec5)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")
print(model.summary())
```

```
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to 
=================================================================================
input_24 (InputLayer)           [(None, 128)]        0    
_________________________________________________________________________________

input_25 (InputLayer)           [(None, 32)]         0                          
  _________________________________________________________________________________

repeat_vector_12 (RepeatVector) (None, 32, 128)      0           input_24[0][0]  
_________________________________________________________________________________

embedding_11 (Embedding)        (None, 32, 128)      128000      input_25[0][0]
_________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_7 (Concatenate)     (None, 32, 256)      0     repeat_vector_12[0][0]
                                                              embedding_11[0][0]
_________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_12 (LSTM)                  (None, 32, 16)       17472    concatenate_7[0][0]
_________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_13 (LSTM)                  (None, 16)           2112        lstm_12[0][0]
_________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 16)           0           lstm_13[0][0]
_________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 32)           544         dropout_2[0][0]
_________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 1000)         33000       dense_4[0][0]
=================================================================================
Total params: 181,128
Trainable params: 181,128
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nicolas Gervais. This is an answer I have been looking